# Subscription Not Created in Database After Session Checkout in Ruby on Rails Pay Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to save my subscription and payment method inside the database after the following code runs but for some reason only the customer get saved and not subscription or payment methods or charges

```
checkout_session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
            mode: 'subscription',
            customer_email: current_user.email,
            locale: I18n.locale,
            line_items: [{
                price: plan.stripe_price_id,
                quantity: 1
            }],
            subscription_data: {
                 'application_fee_amount' => 10,
                metadata: {
                    pay_name: plan.stripe_name, # Optional. Overrides the Pay::Subscription name attribute
                    blog_id: blog.id
                },

            },
            success_url: post_show_url(subdomain: blog.name, id: latest_post.id),
            cancel_url: post_show_url(subdomain: blog.name, id: latest_post.id),
        }, stripe_account: blog.stripe_account_id)
```

Comment: The community will likely need more context to understand your concern and provide suggestions. You mentioned that the problem is Subscription and Payment Methods aren't being saved in your database, but the code you shared is for making a request to the Stripe API to create a Checkout Session. How does that relate to you creating records in your database? Are you trying to leverage pre-existing functionality for making those updates, or did you build your own database update logic? What are you seeing with the approach that you currently have, are there any errors being encountered?

Comment: It's worth noting that Stripe provides an exceptional "developer mode" tool that allows you to run this in test mode and see exactly how it's being received, what problems the API call(s) had, and more. It's absolutely worth checking there first as the API debugger is top-notch.

Comment: Noticing this is a Direct Charge (`application_fee_amount`,`stripe_account`). Are you using `stripe_account` for every other call e.g. when you're fetching the Subscription ? In fact, could you show us how you're saving the data ? - since this appears to be the issue, not the Checkout process you've shared.

Comment: Hi @Lucky2501, @tadman, @toby i have asked the developer and i have gotten a fix, apparently i need to use the ```current_user.pay_customers.find_or_create_by.checkout()``` to create customers connect account. Thanks guys for your response though